# Running ionic on browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am building a hybrid app using ionic 3 .While I try to run it in browser it gives me a "Missing Command Error".It runs on android and ios though.But i wanted to test it on browser too.

Answer (score 1):

Testing your app in a browser is as simple as running the serve command in your project's root folder.

```
ionic serve
```

if you want to run in the ionic lab then run command.

```
ionic serve -l
```